# How to update a Trello card properties using C# API?

Tags: c#, manatee.trello

I am trying to update a Trello card using Manatee Trello API. Here's the code:

```
Run(() =>
{
  TrelloProcessor.WaitForPendingRequests = true;

    var card = new Card("5609144868309d39826b61f1");
    card.Name = "UPDATED: " + card.Name;

    TrelloProcessor.Shutdown();
});

private static void Run(Action action)
{
    var serializer = new ManateeSerializer();
    TrelloConfiguration.Serializer = serializer;
    TrelloConfiguration.Deserializer = serializer;
    TrelloConfiguration.JsonFactory = new ManateeFactory();
    //TrelloConfiguration.RestClientProvider = new RestSharpClientProvider();
    TrelloConfiguration.RestClientProvider = new WebApiClientProvider();

    TrelloAuthorization.Default.AppKey = authKey;
    TrelloAuthorization.Default.UserToken = authToken;

    TrelloConfiguration.ThrowOnTrelloError = true;

    action();
}
```

The code fails complaining about a closed stream. If I put only readonly operations, then everything works fine. What can be a problem here?

Comment: I don't know anything about Trello API, but you would think you would need a StreamReader to read responses, and a StreamWriter to create them.

Comment: You do a lot of Trello configuration, but you never actually send any command to Trello.

Comment: I actuall do, @Dennisch. Look at card.Name update. If I remove this line, everything is fine. Apparently there was a bug in the Manatee library. Should be fixed by now, I will give a new try tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

It appeared that there was a bug in the version 1.0 of Manatee.Trello.WebApi NuGet package. Greg Dennis quickly responded and released version 1.0.1 if his library where this bug was fixed. Now the code posted above works fine.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get to this sooner, Vagif.  I should start monitoring SO for my tags :)

Comment: But you fixed it immediately, Dennis! That's most important.